# Is passing an activity or fragment into static method bad

Tags: android

If I have a method like below:

```
public static void doSomething(Activity aActivity){
    //do Something With The Activity
}
```

Is passing an activity/fragment into a static method a bad idea in terms of memory usage? Could using this method keep a reference to any method alive for the lifetime of the application?

If I have something like this:

```
public static void doSomething(View aView){
    //do Something With The View
}
```

Would this keep the reference to the view alive for the lifetime of the application?

Would these 2 examples, if used enough, cause memory leaks or OOM issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with passing `Activity` or `Context` as a parameter to a `static` method. As long as you do not **store a reference to the `Activity` or `Context` in a `static` variable** there is no memory leak!

Even if you do store a reference in a `static` variable, this would be a small memory leak, because the next call to the method would overwrite the reference, freeing the previously stored object for potential garbage collection. So there is no chance of a situation where gradually over time all the available memory would be consumed.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, but am i wrong in saying that its not good practice in passing activities/fragments to a static method either way?

Comment: No, that is not correct. I see no general problem passing an `Activity` or a `Fragment` to a `static` method. `Activity` is a `Context` and therefore it is passed as a parameter all the time. I can't think of a reason why you would need to pass a `Fragment` to a method, but I'm sure there are valid examples.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a static method and passing it an argument **does not** create memory leaks.

It is bad practice (as D. Wasser and everyone else tell you) in general to store an `Activity` / `Context` / `View` into a static variable, but:

- You can store static variables even from a member method
- `Android Studio` would raise a warning anyway.

Avoid that, and you'll be fine.

Also, from the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips):

> If you don't need to access an object's fields, **make your method static**. Invocations will be about 15%-20% faster. It's also **good practice**, because you can tell from the method signature that calling the method can't alter the object's state.

---

If you do have a `static` method that you use to customize (let's say) you `View`s, I would consider sub-classing the given `View` and specify it's behavior as a private member function.

Answer (score 0):

Passing something into a static function isn't a potential memory leak. Storing a variable in a static variable is. This technique is perfectly safe. Its one I'd even recommend, as you can pass in variables to the function and store them in extras inside the class that is going to use those extras, reducing the number of places that need to know of their existence and how they're laid out.

From

[Passing a activity context into a static method, memory leak potential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480343/passing-a-activity-context-into-a-static-method-memory-leak-potential)

Comment: am i right in saying that this can cause memory leaks or OOM crashes?

Comment: Passing something into a static function isn't a potential memory leak. Storing a variable in a static variable is. This technique is perfectly safe. Its one I'd even recommend, as you can pass in variables to the function and store them in extras inside the class that is going to use those extras, reducing the number of places that need to know of their existence and how they're laid out<br/> Link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480343/passing-a-activity-context-into-a-static-method-memory-leak-potential

Comment: This is nonsense. There is nothing wrong with passing `Activity` or `Context` into a static method.