# Get Intent in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387740/where-how-to-getintent-getextras-in-an-android-fragment) question, it got me thinking. I can get a Intent in a Fragment by calling this inside `onCreateView`:

```
String Item = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

the problem with this is that `getActivity` might return `null`, to counter that I can call:

```
if(getActivity() != null)
    String Item = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
}
```

this  will work fine, but..

---

I was thinking of creating a static method in my Activity and then accessing the Intent in my fragment by calling that method, like this (In my Activity):

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity{
    static String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
        //Getting the Intent from the previous Activity
        name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    }

    public static String Name(){
        //returning the Intent
        return name;
    }

}
```

Then in my Fragment I can call this like this:

```
String name = DemoActivity.Name();
```

---

**My Question:**

Can I do it like this? Will it cause any issues and why?

---

**Currently**

It is working fine.

Comment: its working fine, but static method can always case some memory-leaks. Intent can be preferable.

Comment: @Thunder I'm not storing the `String`, I'm passing it to the `Fragment` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480386/5550161

Comment: `getActivity()` will only return `null` if you created the `Fragment` from outside an `Activity`. If you are always creating the `Fragment` within an `Activity`, then `getActivity()` should never return `null`.

Comment: variable name should be static so that it is accessible by a static method, here the function Name(), cannot return name unless name is a static variable

Comment: @DavidWasser Currently a `Fragment` calls the `Activity` that holds the `Fragment`. In other words, `Activity1` holds a fragment, that fragment starts the second activity `Activity2` and `Activity2` holds the fragment I want to get the intent.

Comment: @RameesThattarath Can you please elaborate? Are you talking about `String name;` should be `static String name;`? It works fine currently by just setting it as `String name;`

Comment: `Fragment`s don't **call** `Activity`s. They launch them. In most cases, a `Fragment` is tied to an `Activity`, which means that getActivity()` will never return `null`. It only returns `null` in special cases where the `Fragment` is created but not associated with an `Activity`.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can do `String Item = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");` without worrying about `getActivity()` returning `null`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Creates is what I meant. So I don't have to worry about the `getActivity` returning `null`. Call you please clarify why what I'm doing is not correct?

Comment: Static methods cannot refernce instance variables as instance variables are meant for each objects and static method is called over the class name and not with respect to any objects-
This code should return following error
non-static variable name cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: You can also do what you are doing. It is just unnecessarily complicated. There's nothing wrong with it. There are many ways to do things in software. Your approach is just unnecessarily convoluted. It also doesn't solve the problem. If your `Fragment` can exist without the `Activity`, then theoretically `DemoActivity.Name()` can **also** return `null`!

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for. I know that a `Fragment` cannot exist on its own that is why `getActivity()` must be called. It just makes more sense to me doing it this way. That is why I asked the question to find out if there is any difference.

Comment: @RameesThattarath `This code should return following error non-static variable name cannot be referenced from a static context` Sorry you are right, in the question it is not static, but in my code it is. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

try like this:

Activity class:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("your_key", "your_value");
 your_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment class:

```
String your_variable = getArguments().getString("your_key");
```

Comment: `Bundle` is created in a Fragment of the previous Activity.

Comment: `Bundle` is attached to the fragment to be created, and you can verify his existance wtih `if(getArguments() != null && getArguments.containsKey("your_key"))` validation. This is the best practice and most common one to use. Regarding your question, what would happen if your activity gets destroyed? Maybe we are not understanding what's your goal here. You just want to pass data from an Activity to a fragment? Is that it?

Comment: I want to pass data from a Fragment in one Activity to a Fragment in another Activity.

Comment: @HB.   I have posted another answer for above qusetion

Answer (score 1):

Set in first activity fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("your_string_key", "your_value");

startActivity(new Intent(getActivity() your_second_activity.class).putExtra("bundle_key", bundle));
```

Get bundle value second activity:

```
fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle_key"));
```

In Second Activity Fragment:

```
getArguments().getString("your_string_key")
```

Comment: you want to pass data from first activity fragment to second activity fragment right???

Comment: `My Question` -> Can I do it like this? Will it cause any issues and why?

Comment: Yeah you can do.. no issue

Comment: something is wrong in Kotlin.  not working -- everything is null from the Activity to the Fragment.  there are constructs of "arguments" and requiresArgs() and nothing is working as expected.  back to the books!  Once again the compiler geniuses of Kotlin compiler has taken a simple, working concept and made it impossible to get right.